# jQuery radio button select only one (ID)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 groups raido buttons, they have different unique IDs, how to make they can be selected only one for each group. Thanks

```
<group>
<input type="radio" id="u1"/>1
<input type="radio" id="u2"/>2
<input type="radio" id="u3"/>3
</div >
</group>


<group>
<input type="radio" id="T1"/>4
<input type="radio" id="T2"/>5
<input type="radio" id="T3"/>6
</group>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pZdWu/

I don't want to change the html, just want to use jQuery to achieve

Comment: Why don't you want to change the HTML? It's the default behavior for radio buttons and does exactly what you want...

Comment: The `group` element? Really? Does that even exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really must use the existing HTML, then I'd suggest amending the HTML via jQuery to simply use the default functions of a radio input:

```
​$('group').each(
    function(i,e){
        $(e).find('input:radio').attr('name', 'group' + i);
    });​​​​​
```

[JS fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pZdWu/4/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: @DavidThomas IGNORE ME. Haha I don't know why, but somehow I missed exactly what you were doing and assumed you were doing the whole "checked" true/false thing like most of us used. Just nevermind, I should've taken more than 2 seconds to read the answer. That's why I deleted the comment :)

Comment: No problem at all! I actually have trouble, sometimes, remembering what's an *attribute* and what's a *property*, so I just assumed you were right (though I did post a comment asking for an explanation, I don't know if you'd have seen it before I deleted it following your deletion of your original comment...) =)

Comment: Haha yeah I know, attributes and properties have confused me now that jQuery pointed it out in their API and forced me to understand :). I think in this particular case, using either `attr` or `prop` is fine - I tested `prop` with your fiddle and that still seems to work, but `attr` makes more sense here anyways.

Comment: I am a beginner, what is `i,e` argument?

Comment: The `i` is the index of the current element of the group returned by the selector over which the `each()` method is iterating. The `e` is the current node (not a jQuery object, hence the `$(e)` in the next line within the method). Incidentally, had you looked at the references at the foot of my answer would have explained that. Research is important.

Answer (score 1):

Give each item in the group a common name using the name attribute.....

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="u1"/>1
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="u2"/>2
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="u3"/>3
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention I don't want to change html, just want to use jQuery. do I need to prepend `name` tag for each `id`?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can use something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pZdWu/5/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.siblings("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", false);
    });
});
```

But this assumes your HTML structure is exactly as you provided.

If the radio buttons have any kind of wrapping HTML on them, or are grouped inside any way, the use of `siblings` won't work. You might have to use something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/pZdWu/7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.parents("group:first").find("input[type=radio]").not($this).prop("checked", false);
    });
});
```

And obviously change the use of "group" to whatever you are actually using (I thought I saw you edited your original question to not use `<group>`).